# Awaiting re-render of InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an `ImagesContainer` component showing a paginated list of `ImageCard` components, it's populated from a database service call. When the user selects a new page, I call the service and fetch the updated list relevant to page number and page size.

I must rely on `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` to update the page after this due to some markup conditionals I have set up (show spinner at page load and other scenarios, etc.).

Now I want to implement a selection system to select some of the images with a checkbox on the `ImageCard`. I have a `Manager Service` that handles app state and events, it holds a `List<int>` containing the selected image's ids, as well as the relevant methods to Add, Remove and Clear the list that are called from the `ImageCard` when the checkbox state changes. I also trigger an `OnSelectedImagesChanged` event whenever those methods are called to manage some UI related concerns like showing/hiding interaction buttons according to the list element count.

After `ImagesContainer` has been updated from the pagination, I need to update each component inside it in order to reflect the state of the checkbox, otherwise the child `ImageCard` component that was checked by the user will retain it's checked state regardless of the fact that it´s new `Image.Id` is or isn't present in the selected images list from the `Manager Service`, even if the actual img element changes on the component.

To handle this I created an `OnRefreshImages` event that is triggered from the pagination method via the `Manager Service` and is consumed by the `ImageCard`, when it's called in the component I check if the card's Image.Id is present in the selected images list and set the checked state to that. So in the end, this is my pseudo code for the `LoadImages()`:

```cs
private async Task LoadImages()
{
    // Call Database Service to fetch current page's Image entities  

    // Updates the page with the new image list 
    await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged); 

    // Trigger event to refresh ImagesContainer´s ImageCard child components in order to set checked state
    ManagerService.RefreshImages();
}
```

The problem happens after the `StateHasChanged` call, it seems to be running in a synchronously "fire and forget" fashion (I'm assuming that's because `StateHasChanged` returns void and not Task) because `OnRefreshImages` event is triggered before the page is re-rendered and, at that point, the `ImagesContainer` still holds the old `ImageCard` components from before the pagination.

Inserting a `await Task.Delay(1000)` between the 2 calls fixes the problem and the `OnRefreshImages` is now called on the repopulated container but having an arbitrarily hard-coded delay isn't very pretty and this is a bad user experience because of the delayed state update.

Should I have an `IsSelected` property in the Image model that is initiated after the call to the database service? Would that prevent the need to have the `OnRefreshImages` event and update the `ImageCard` component automatically during the `StateHasChanged`?

EDIT: More context on the `Gallery` page markup that contains the `ImagesContainer`:

```cs
@if (_projects == null)
{
    <LoadingSpinner />
}
else if (_projects.Count() == 0 && ManagerService.State.Gallery.FolderId == 0)
{
    <CreateProjectForm />
}
else
{
    if (images != null && images.Images != null && images.Images.Count > 0)
    {
        <ImagesContainer @ref=_imagesContainer Images="@images" />
    }
    else if (images.Images.Count == 0)
    {
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h5">Empty Project</MudText>
    }
    else
    {
        <LoadingSpinner />
    }
}
```

The application uses "Projects" as folders to keep images organized. Here I show a spinner while the `_projects` variable is being populated by the `OnAfterRenderAsync` override (can't recall why I choose this over `OnInitializedAsync` but maybe this is where the problem lies). After the projects are fetched from the database I call the `LoadImages()` to populate the relevant project images.

The `StateHasChanged` call is mainly used to re-render the page after initialization because for some reason the page doesn't refresh after the `_projects` variable is initialized from the database call and it gets stuck showing the loading spinner as if `_projects` is still null.

`ManagerService.RefreshImages()` purpose is just a trigger to let the manager propagate the event of `OnRefreshImages` to refresh the `ImageCard` components after the `ImageContainer` is updated via loading a new pagination page or other interactions. This is the implementation:

`public void RefreshImages() => OnRefreshImages?.Invoke();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without reviewing the actual code, I'm making some educated guesses.  However, based on your description of your code I can make the following observations.

You should only need to call `StateHasChanged` to:

1. Update the UI during an UI event when you want to present Status while the Ui event is running.
2. In an event handler, such as you describe above.

In almost all other circumstances, calls to `StateHasChanged` force the UI to update to cover up logic problems (that often come back to haunt you at a later date!)

> "I must rely on await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged) to update the page after this due to some markup conditionals I have set up (show spinner at page load and other scenarios, etc.)."

Sounds like your logic may be wrong, unless 1 above applies.

Calling `StateHasChanged` doesn't render the component: it queues a `RenderFragment` on the Renderer's queue.  The Renderer can only service its queue when it gets thread time to do so.

You're `LoadImages` is a synchronous code block wrapped in a `Task`.  `StateHasChanged` is a synchronous function - it's just loading the queue. `ManagerService.RefreshImages();` looks like a sync method, so the Renderer only gets thread time once  `LoadImages` completes.  Adding the await `Task.Delay` solves that by yielding and giving the Renderer thread time.  You only need a `Delay(1)`.  `await Task.Yield()` also works.

Comment: I provided a bit more context, not sure if it's clearer. I think I understand the concept better now, but the `LoadImages()` does async calls to the DatabaseService to get the image entities, shouldn't the method have thread time by that? Or does it need to happen after the `StateHasChanged` like the `Task.Yield` achieves?

You're right the `ManagerService.RefreshImages()` does this `public void RefreshImages() => OnRefreshImages?.Invoke();`, it's simply triggering the event from the manager to be propagated to the `ImageCard` components. Thanks for the help Shaun.

Comment: All your data loading should be in `OnInitializedAsync` or sometimes in `OnParametersSetAsync` if the logic requires.  `OnAfterRenderAsync` should only be used for post rendering JS interop stuff.  In `OnInitializedAsync` you take advantage of the built in double render in `ComponentBase`'s UI handler - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-7.0#lifecycle-events.  Also see this article - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5277618/A-Dive-into-Blazor-Components - for more detail on components.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll read it more thoroughly later. I try to follow that principle but for some reason I left the initialization on this page as `OnAfterRenderAsync` and just noticed now, perhaps I was trying some different logic at the time and left it by mistake. Think I'll accept the answer, I still use the `await Task.Yield()` as a quick fix but I understand the problem a bit better now.

Comment: @Hugo - NP.  The single most important concept to understand in Blazor is components.  Building a thorough understanding will save you lots of design and debugging time down the road.